# Customize SeekBar in Android

Tags: android, seekbar

I use a seekbar in my application and would like to customize it.

I want to change the drawable(I want to use my own image).
How to do it?

Answer (score 3):

From the code:

```
Drawable thumb = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.slider_thumb);              
mSlider.setThumb(thumb);
mSlider.setProgressDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.slider_track));
```

mSlider is a [SeekBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.html).